# Working with Pages in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have noticed an interesting issue with how jQuery treats hyper links. According to the doc, clicking on a link will trigger a AJAX call and the requested page's contents are stuffed in the current's pages DOM.

Now consider this, index.html has a hyperlink which points to location.html. Inside location.html I'm using  `window.onload = getMyLocation ;` to trigger a call to a JavaScript function. Since jQuery mobile just picks up the code within data-role of page, my JavaScipt code never gets a chace to run and as a result I need to explicitly refresh the page. Is there a workaround?

Thanks
KJ

Answer (score 0):

Can you not trigger the JavaScript function from an event fired within your hyperlink, i.e.

```
<a href="#location.html" onClick="[...]">Location</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#location.html" id="locbutton">Location</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#locbutton").live( "click", function(){
    [...]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the pagebeforeshow event, to get the same effect as onload.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```